# Is it ok to hang a ceiling fan from an Iberville Octagonal Box 1-1/2 Inch AC90 Steel Stud?

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image: octagon electric box]

Iberville Octagonal Box 1-1/2 Inch AC90 Steel Stud

I'm trying to figure if I can mount a 30lb fan (as per specification full installed weight) to this box?

We are in a townhouse condo and don't think we have access to attic. I did find the label on the box and it's exactly the box in the pic. The two screws on the box that would be used for fan mount would take 8-32 machine screws. I am thinking of using them with hex nuts for extra protection.
But is this box ok for mounting the fan? Or if not, how do we switch it, as not sure how to get in attic.

Also it has two pipes of wiring coming into it with bigger nuts to hold the pipe. It seems pretty stable if it try to move by hand.

Same is available in home depot : [link](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/iberville-octagonal-box-1-1-2-inch-ac90-steel-stud/1000805183)

Comment: I take it that's the box that's already in the ceiling, no?

Comment: From the HD link, the description of the box reads "Octagonal box to install a light fixture or to serve as a junction box". It does _not_ indicate that it's rated for a ceiling fan, so I'd say "no". The 30 lb fan weight does _not_ include the vibrations from the fan running. A search of their site for _ceiling fan box_ yields only one option which is not explicitly for a steel stud situation. You may need to check other retailers.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the box itself, nor any of it sales literature, indicates that it’s fan-rated.  If it were, they’d be shouting that pretty loudly, because it’s a major feature.

### Fan-rated boxes are *special*

Because fans are not a static load.  A 30-pound chandelier just hangs there.  A 30-pound fan *vibrates and shakes*.  These dynamic forces are what make ceiling fan boxes so critical/tough.

If you install a ceiling fan on a non-fan-rated box, it is likely to cause fatigue failure in the box or fasteners, and drop a spinning fan on somebody’s head.